# HTML5: Label vs Id

Tags: html

Just wondering, when it comes to HTML5, what is the difference between a label and an id?

Do you always need a label if you have an id, or does an id belong in a label?

Thanks

Comment: A "label" is an element and the "id" an attribute. they have different purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Label**

The `<label>` tag defines a label for an `<input>` element.

The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles the control.

The `for` attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the `id` attribute of the related element to bind them together.

```html
<p>Clicking the word "Agree" will check the agree checkbox
 because they are linked by the <code>for</code> attribute:</p>
 <input type="checkbox" id="agree"><label for="agree">Agree<label>
 
 <p>Without linking them via <code>for</code> you have to click
 on the checkbox itself:</p>
 <input type="checkbox" id="email"><label>E-mail me updates<label>
```

**Id**

The `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The `id` attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific `id`.

The `label` is not mandatory if you have an `id`. They are independent attributes.

Comment: No problem. I hope It was helpful.